# ¿Cómo superponer un DIV sobre un CANVAS o un fondo de PLUGIN de JAVASCRIPT?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, sass

- Realizo la importación a mi **HTML** para ejecutar el plugin, los tags (script) que se ecuentran al final de mi (body) son los encargados de darle funcionamiento a mi plugin.
- También necesito configurarlo en **CSS** a través de la class="background" que se encuentra en mi tag (canvas) después del (div) en el header.

```js
// particles.min.js
var Particles=function(e,t){"use strict";var n,i={};function o(e,t){return e.x<t.x?-1:e.x>t.x?1:e.y<t.y?-1:e.y>t.y?1:0}return(n=function(){return function(){var e=this;e.defaults={responsive:null,selector:null,maxParticles:100,sizeVariations:3,showParticles:!0,speed:.5,color:"#000000",minDistance:120,connectParticles:!1},e.element=null,e.context=null,e.ratio=null,e.breakpoints=[],e.activeBreakpoint=null,e.breakpointSettings=[],e.originalSettings=null,e.storage=[],e.usingPolyfill=!1}}()).prototype.init=function(e){var t=this;return t.options=t._extend(t.defaults,e),t.originalSettings=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(t.options)),t._animate=t._animate.bind(t),t._initializeCanvas(),t._initializeEvents(),t._registerBreakpoints(),t._checkResponsive(),t._initializeStorage(),t._animate(),t},n.prototype.destroy=function(){var t=this;t.storage=[],t.element.remove(),e.removeEventListener("resize",t.listener,!1),e.clearTimeout(t._animation),cancelAnimationFrame(t._animation)},n.prototype._initializeCanvas=function(){var n,i,o=this;if(!o.options.selector)return console.warn("particles.js: No selector specified! Check https://github.com/marcbruederlin/particles.js#options"),!1;o.element=t.querySelector(o.options.selector),o.context=o.element.getContext("2d"),n=e.devicePixelRatio||1,i=o.context.webkitBackingStorePixelRatio||o.context.mozBackingStorePixelRatio||o.context.msBackingStorePixelRatio||o.context.oBackingStorePixelRatio||o.context.backingStorePixelRatio||1,o.ratio=n/i,o.element.width=o.element.offsetParent?o.element.offsetParent.clientWidth*o.ratio:o.element.clientWidth*o.ratio,o.element.offsetParent&&"BODY"===o.element.offsetParent.nodeName?o.element.height=e.innerHeight*o.ratio:o.element.height=o.element.offsetParent?o.element.offsetParent.clientHeight*o.ratio:o.element.clientHeight*o.ratio,o.element.style.width="100%",o.element.style.height="100%",o.context.scale(o.ratio,o.ratio)},n.prototype._initializeEvents=function(){var t=this;t.listener=function(){t._resize()}.bind(this),e.addEventListener("resize",t.listener,!1)},n.prototype._initializeStorage=function(){var e=this;e.storage=[];for(var t=e.options.maxParticles;t--;)e.storage.push(new i(e.context,e.options))},n.prototype._registerBreakpoints=function(){var e,t,n,i=this,o=i.options.responsive||null;if("object"==typeof o&&null!==o&&o.length){for(e in o)if(n=i.breakpoints.length-1,t=o[e].breakpoint,o.hasOwnProperty(e)){for(;n>=0;)i.breakpoints[n]&&i.breakpoints[n]===t&&i.breakpoints.splice(n,1),n--;i.breakpoints.push(t),i.breakpointSettings[t]=o[e].options}i.breakpoints.sort(function(e,t){return t-e})}},n.prototype._checkResponsive=function(){var t,n=this,i=!1,o=e.innerWidth;if(n.options.responsive&&n.options.responsive.length&&null!==n.options.responsive){for(t in i=null,n.breakpoints)n.breakpoints.hasOwnProperty(t)&&o<=n.breakpoints[t]&&(i=n.breakpoints[t]);null!==i?(n.activeBreakpoint=i,n.options=n._extend(n.options,n.breakpointSettings[i])):null!==n.activeBreakpoint&&(n.activeBreakpoint=null,i=null,n.options=n._extend(n.options,n.originalSettings))}},n.prototype._refresh=function(){this._initializeStorage(),this._draw()},n.prototype._resize=function(){var t=this;t.element.width=t.element.offsetParent?t.element.offsetParent.clientWidth*t.ratio:t.element.clientWidth*t.ratio,t.element.offsetParent&&"BODY"===t.element.offsetParent.nodeName?t.element.height=e.innerHeight*t.ratio:t.element.height=t.element.offsetParent?t.element.offsetParent.clientHeight*t.ratio:t.element.clientHeight*t.ratio,t.context.scale(t.ratio,t.ratio),clearTimeout(t.windowDelay),t.windowDelay=e.setTimeout(function(){t._checkResponsive(),t._refresh()},50)},n.prototype._animate=function(){var t=this;t._draw(),t._animation=e.requestAnimFrame(t._animate)},n.prototype.resumeAnimation=function(){this._animation||this._animate()},n.prototype.pauseAnimation=function(){var t=this;if(t._animation){if(t.usingPolyfill)e.clearTimeout(t._animation);else(e.cancelAnimationFrame||e.webkitCancelAnimationFrame||e.mozCancelAnimationFrame)(t._animation);t._animation=null}},n.prototype._draw=function(){var t=this,n=t.element,i=n.offsetParent?n.offsetParent.clientWidth:n.clientWidth,r=n.offsetParent?n.offsetParent.clientHeight:n.clientHeight,a=t.options.showParticles,s=t.storage;n.offsetParent&&"BODY"===n.offsetParent.nodeName&&(r=e.innerHeight),t.context.clearRect(0,0,n.width,n.height),t.context.beginPath();for(var l=s.length;l--;){var c=s[l];a&&c._draw(),c._updateCoordinates(i,r)}t.options.connectParticles&&(s.sort(o),t._updateEdges())},n.prototype._updateEdges=function(){for(var e=this,t=e.options.minDistance,n=Math.sqrt,i=Math.abs,o=e.storage,r=o.length,a=0;a<r;a++)for(var s=o[a],l=a+1;l<r;l++){var c,f=o[l],p=s.x-f.x,h=s.y-f.y;if(c=n(p*p+h*h),i(p)>t)break;c<=t&&e._drawEdge(s,f,1.2-c/t)}},n.prototype._drawEdge=function(e,t,n){var i=this,o=i.context.createLinearGradient(e.x,e.y,t.x,t.y),r=this._hex2rgb(e.color),a=this._hex2rgb(t.color);o.addColorStop(0,"rgba("+r.r+","+r.g+","+r.b+","+n+")"),o.addColorStop(1,"rgba("+a.r+","+a.g+","+a.b+","+n+")"),i.context.beginPath(),i.context.strokeStyle=o,i.context.moveTo(e.x,e.y),i.context.lineTo(t.x,t.y),i.context.stroke(),i.context.fill(),i.context.closePath()},n.prototype._extend=function(e,t){return Object.keys(t).forEach(function(n){e[n]=t[n]}),e},n.prototype._hex2rgb=function(e){var t=/^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(e);return t?{r:parseInt(t[1],16),g:parseInt(t[2],16),b:parseInt(t[3],16)}:null},(i=function(n,i){var o=this,r=Math.random,a=i.speed,s=i.color instanceof Array?i.color[Math.floor(Math.random()*i.color.length)]:i.color;o.context=n,o.options=i;var l=t.querySelector(i.selector);o.x=l.offsetParent?r()*l.offsetParent.clientWidth:r()*l.clientWidth,l.offsetParent&&"BODY"===l.offsetParent.nodeName?o.y=r()*e.innerHeight:o.y=l.offsetParent?r()*l.offsetParent.clientHeight:r()*l.clientHeight,o.vx=r()*a*2-a,o.vy=r()*a*2-a,o.radius=r()*r()*i.sizeVariations,o.color=s,o._draw()}).prototype._draw=function(){var e=this;e.context.save(),e.context.translate(e.x,e.y),e.context.moveTo(0,0),e.context.beginPath(),e.context.arc(0,0,e.radius,0,2*Math.PI,!1),e.context.fillStyle=e.color,e.context.fill(),e.context.restore()},i.prototype._updateCoordinates=function(e,t){var n=this,i=n.x+this.vx,o=n.y+this.vy,r=n.radius;i+r>e?i=r:i-r<0&&(i=e-r),o+r>t?o=r:o-r<0&&(o=t-r),n.x=i,n.y=o},e.requestAnimFrame=function(){var t=e.requestAnimationFrame||e.webkitRequestAnimationFrame||e.mozRequestAnimationFrame;return t||(this._usingPolyfill=!0,function(t){return e.setTimeout(t,1e3/60)})}(),new n}(window,document);!function(){"use strict";"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define("Particles",function(){return Particles}):"undefined"!=typeof module&&module.exports?module.exports=Particles:window.Particles=Particles}();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Atkinson Hyperlegible", sans-serif;
}

.header__introduction {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #d6f2ff;
}

.background {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Figuras Geométricas | Curso Práctico de JavaScript de Platzi</title>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Atkinson+Hyperlegible&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./figures_styles.css">
</head>
<script src="./figures.js"></script>

<body>
  <header class="header">
    <div class="header__introduction">
      <h1>Figuras geométricas</h1>
      <p>Este es el primer taller del curso práctico de JavaScript</p>
    </div>
    <canvas class="background"></canvas>
  </header>
  <script src="./node_modules/particlesjs/dist/particles.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Run Background.
    window.onload = function() {
      Particles.init({
        selector: '.background',
        color: '#87b7ff',
        maxParticles: 110,
        connectParticles: true,
        responsive: [{
            breakpoint: 947,
            options: {
              maxParticles: 100
            }
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 847,
            options: {
              maxParticles: 90
            }
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 647,
            options: {
              maxParticles: 76
            }
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 477,
            options: {
              maxParticles: 46
            }
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 300,
            options: {
              maxParticles: 26
            }
          }
        ]
      });
    };
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Código en el **preprocesador SASS**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Atkinson Hyperlegible", sans-serif;
}

.header__introduction {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgb(214, 242, 255);
}
.background {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

***Lo que no logro hacer es superponer ese tag (div) sobre el canvas, intente muchas cosas y aún así no quiere funcionar...***
Esta es la distribución a la cual llamo para que comience a ejecutarse el plugin, en los script voy a importar un archivo **particles.min.js**

Comment: Ya los tienes superpuestos, lo que deseas es darle orden en "direccion z". He testeado y funciona ponerle un `z-index` al texto.

Comment: Eres lo máximo amigo, funciona!
Gracias 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es:

- El contenedor padre con posición relativa, para que los elementos internos se posicionen respecto a este
- Asignar medidas fijas y fondo al contenedor padre
- En HTML colocar primero el canvas y debajo el elemento con información
- El elemento con información debe tener posición absoluta para aparecer arriba del canvas y los límites (top, bottom, left y right) en cero para ocupar todo el espacio disponible

```js
// particles.min.js
var Particles=function(e,t){"use strict";var n,i={};function o(e,t){return e.x<t.x?-1:e.x>t.x?1:e.y<t.y?-1:e.y>t.y?1:0}return(n=function(){return function(){var e=this;e.defaults={responsive:null,selector:null,maxParticles:100,sizeVariations:3,showParticles:!0,speed:.5,color:"#000000",minDistance:120,connectParticles:!1},e.element=null,e.context=null,e.ratio=null,e.breakpoints=[],e.activeBreakpoint=null,e.breakpointSettings=[],e.originalSettings=null,e.storage=[],e.usingPolyfill=!1}}()).prototype.init=function(e){var t=this;return t.options=t._extend(t.defaults,e),t.originalSettings=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(t.options)),t._animate=t._animate.bind(t),t._initializeCanvas(),t._initializeEvents(),t._registerBreakpoints(),t._checkResponsive(),t._initializeStorage(),t._animate(),t},n.prototype.destroy=function(){var t=this;t.storage=[],t.element.remove(),e.removeEventListener("resize",t.listener,!1),e.clearTimeout(t._animation),cancelAnimationFrame(t._animation)},n.prototype._initializeCanvas=function(){var n,i,o=this;if(!o.options.selector)return console.warn("particles.js: No selector specified! Check https://github.com/marcbruederlin/particles.js#options"),!1;o.element=t.querySelector(o.options.selector),o.context=o.element.getContext("2d"),n=e.devicePixelRatio||1,i=o.context.webkitBackingStorePixelRatio||o.context.mozBackingStorePixelRatio||o.context.msBackingStorePixelRatio||o.context.oBackingStorePixelRatio||o.context.backingStorePixelRatio||1,o.ratio=n/i,o.element.width=o.element.offsetParent?o.element.offsetParent.clientWidth*o.ratio:o.element.clientWidth*o.ratio,o.element.offsetParent&&"BODY"===o.element.offsetParent.nodeName?o.element.height=e.innerHeight*o.ratio:o.element.height=o.element.offsetParent?o.element.offsetParent.clientHeight*o.ratio:o.element.clientHeight*o.ratio,o.element.style.width="100%",o.element.style.height="100%",o.context.scale(o.ratio,o.ratio)},n.prototype._initializeEvents=function(){var t=this;t.listener=function(){t._resize()}.bind(this),e.addEventListener("resize",t.listener,!1)},n.prototype._initializeStorage=function(){var e=this;e.storage=[];for(var t=e.options.maxParticles;t--;)e.storage.push(new i(e.context,e.options))},n.prototype._registerBreakpoints=function(){var e,t,n,i=this,o=i.options.responsive||null;if("object"==typeof o&&null!==o&&o.length){for(e in o)if(n=i.breakpoints.length-1,t=o[e].breakpoint,o.hasOwnProperty(e)){for(;n>=0;)i.breakpoints[n]&&i.breakpoints[n]===t&&i.breakpoints.splice(n,1),n--;i.breakpoints.push(t),i.breakpointSettings[t]=o[e].options}i.breakpoints.sort(function(e,t){return t-e})}},n.prototype._checkResponsive=function(){var t,n=this,i=!1,o=e.innerWidth;if(n.options.responsive&&n.options.responsive.length&&null!==n.options.responsive){for(t in i=null,n.breakpoints)n.breakpoints.hasOwnProperty(t)&&o<=n.breakpoints[t]&&(i=n.breakpoints[t]);null!==i?(n.activeBreakpoint=i,n.options=n._extend(n.options,n.breakpointSettings[i])):null!==n.activeBreakpoint&&(n.activeBreakpoint=null,i=null,n.options=n._extend(n.options,n.originalSettings))}},n.prototype._refresh=function(){this._initializeStorage(),this._draw()},n.prototype._resize=function(){var t=this;t.element.width=t.element.offsetParent?t.element.offsetParent.clientWidth*t.ratio:t.element.clientWidth*t.ratio,t.element.offsetParent&&"BODY"===t.element.offsetParent.nodeName?t.element.height=e.innerHeight*t.ratio:t.element.height=t.element.offsetParent?t.element.offsetParent.clientHeight*t.ratio:t.element.clientHeight*t.ratio,t.context.scale(t.ratio,t.ratio),clearTimeout(t.windowDelay),t.windowDelay=e.setTimeout(function(){t._checkResponsive(),t._refresh()},50)},n.prototype._animate=function(){var t=this;t._draw(),t._animation=e.requestAnimFrame(t._animate)},n.prototype.resumeAnimation=function(){this._animation||this._animate()},n.prototype.pauseAnimation=function(){var t=this;if(t._animation){if(t.usingPolyfill)e.clearTimeout(t._animation);else(e.cancelAnimationFrame||e.webkitCancelAnimationFrame||e.mozCancelAnimationFrame)(t._animation);t._animation=null}},n.prototype._draw=function(){var t=this,n=t.element,i=n.offsetParent?n.offsetParent.clientWidth:n.clientWidth,r=n.offsetParent?n.offsetParent.clientHeight:n.clientHeight,a=t.options.showParticles,s=t.storage;n.offsetParent&&"BODY"===n.offsetParent.nodeName&&(r=e.innerHeight),t.context.clearRect(0,0,n.width,n.height),t.context.beginPath();for(var l=s.length;l--;){var c=s[l];a&&c._draw(),c._updateCoordinates(i,r)}t.options.connectParticles&&(s.sort(o),t._updateEdges())},n.prototype._updateEdges=function(){for(var e=this,t=e.options.minDistance,n=Math.sqrt,i=Math.abs,o=e.storage,r=o.length,a=0;a<r;a++)for(var s=o[a],l=a+1;l<r;l++){var c,f=o[l],p=s.x-f.x,h=s.y-f.y;if(c=n(p*p+h*h),i(p)>t)break;c<=t&&e._drawEdge(s,f,1.2-c/t)}},n.prototype._drawEdge=function(e,t,n){var i=this,o=i.context.createLinearGradient(e.x,e.y,t.x,t.y),r=this._hex2rgb(e.color),a=this._hex2rgb(t.color);o.addColorStop(0,"rgba("+r.r+","+r.g+","+r.b+","+n+")"),o.addColorStop(1,"rgba("+a.r+","+a.g+","+a.b+","+n+")"),i.context.beginPath(),i.context.strokeStyle=o,i.context.moveTo(e.x,e.y),i.context.lineTo(t.x,t.y),i.context.stroke(),i.context.fill(),i.context.closePath()},n.prototype._extend=function(e,t){return Object.keys(t).forEach(function(n){e[n]=t[n]}),e},n.prototype._hex2rgb=function(e){var t=/^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(e);return t?{r:parseInt(t[1],16),g:parseInt(t[2],16),b:parseInt(t[3],16)}:null},(i=function(n,i){var o=this,r=Math.random,a=i.speed,s=i.color instanceof Array?i.color[Math.floor(Math.random()*i.color.length)]:i.color;o.context=n,o.options=i;var l=t.querySelector(i.selector);o.x=l.offsetParent?r()*l.offsetParent.clientWidth:r()*l.clientWidth,l.offsetParent&&"BODY"===l.offsetParent.nodeName?o.y=r()*e.innerHeight:o.y=l.offsetParent?r()*l.offsetParent.clientHeight:r()*l.clientHeight,o.vx=r()*a*2-a,o.vy=r()*a*2-a,o.radius=r()*r()*i.sizeVariations,o.color=s,o._draw()}).prototype._draw=function(){var e=this;e.context.save(),e.context.translate(e.x,e.y),e.context.moveTo(0,0),e.context.beginPath(),e.context.arc(0,0,e.radius,0,2*Math.PI,!1),e.context.fillStyle=e.color,e.context.fill(),e.context.restore()},i.prototype._updateCoordinates=function(e,t){var n=this,i=n.x+this.vx,o=n.y+this.vy,r=n.radius;i+r>e?i=r:i-r<0&&(i=e-r),o+r>t?o=r:o-r<0&&(o=t-r),n.x=i,n.y=o},e.requestAnimFrame=function(){var t=e.requestAnimationFrame||e.webkitRequestAnimationFrame||e.mozRequestAnimationFrame;return t||(this._usingPolyfill=!0,function(t){return e.setTimeout(t,1e3/60)})}(),new n}(window,document);!function(){"use strict";"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define("Particles",function(){return Particles}):"undefined"!=typeof module&&module.exports?module.exports=Particles:window.Particles=Particles}();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Atkinson Hyperlegible", sans-serif;
}
/* header con posición relativa, medidas fijas y fondo de color */
.header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #d6f2ff;
}
/* Información con posición absoluta */
.header__introduction {
  position: absolute;
  /* Todos los límites en cero para ocupar todo el espacio disponible */
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}
/* Esto no parece ser necesario, se adapta al espacio disponible */
.background {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Figuras Geométricas | Curso Práctico de JavaScript de Platzi</title>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Atkinson+Hyperlegible&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./figures_styles.css">
</head>
<script src="./figures.js"></script>

<body>
  <header class="header">
    <canvas class="background"></canvas>
    <div class="header__introduction">
      <h1>Figuras geométricas</h1>
      <p>Este es el primer taller del curso práctico de JavaScript</p>
    </div>
  </header>
  <script src="./node_modules/particlesjs/dist/particles.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Run Background.
    window.onload = function() {
      Particles.init({
        selector: '.background',
        color: '#87b7ff',
        maxParticles: 110,
        connectParticles: true,
        responsive: [{
            breakpoint: 947,
            options: {
              maxParticles: 100
            }
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 847,
            options: {
              maxParticles: 90
            }
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 647,
            options: {
              maxParticles: 76
            }
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 477,
            options: {
              maxParticles: 46
            }
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 300,
            options: {
              maxParticles: 26
            }
          }
        ]
      });
    };
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```